Receive Error StatusCode 415 when try to POST to an endpoint in C# ASP.NET Core Web API
I have an ApiTester in HomeController. When ApiTester loaded, it will make a POST request to an API method in AuthController.
Home Index page contains Link to try the api:
<a href="@Url.Action("ApiTester", "Home")">ApiTester Click Here</a>

This is my HomeController class:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using TestWebApplication.Models;

namespace TestWebApplication.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ApiTester()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Name", "Alice" } };
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:7284/api/Auth/ApiTest", content);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                ViewBag.ApiResponse = result;
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.ApiResponse = "Error: " + response.StatusCode;
            }

            return View();
        }
    }
}

This is the AuthController class:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace TestWebApplication.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("GetTest")]
        public IActionResult GetTest()
        {
            return Ok(new { message = "Get Test Succesfull!" });
        }

        [HttpPost("ApiTest")]
        public IActionResult ApiTest([FromBody] Dictionary<string, string> values)
        {
            string name = values["name"];
            return Ok(new { message = "200: Post Test Succesfull!" });
        }
    }
}

Nothing fancy in my program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

I receive the Error:UnsupportedMediaType. What could be causing this? When I remove the ApiTest val like this:
public IActionResult ApiTest()
.
.

It runs smoothly.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Inside the VS's output did it contains more details information? Besides, please share the authcontroller and the program.cs to let us reproduce the issue.

Try modify your HttpPost method in the following way:
        [HttpPost("ApiTest")]
        [Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
        public IActionResult ApiTest([FromForm] Dictionary<string, string> values)
        {
            string name = values["name"];
            return Ok(new { message = "200: Post Test Succesfull!" });
        }

Note Consumes attribute and FromBody becoming FromForm

adding [Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")] works. I wish theres a way I can do this globally without needting to put this on all controller endpoint.
